# Date with format and locale

Tags: android, simpledateformat, chinese-locale, android-date

I am trying to get the date with this pattern - "dd/MM/yyyy".
So far i've used SimpleDateFormat to achieve it, but now i need to also support Chinese in my app and it's not giving me the result i need.

I'm trying to make it look like the pattern with attention to the locale:
English: 16/05/2016
Chinese: 2016年05月16日

I tried different options - 
 android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateTime
 android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat

but couldn't get the result i wanted.
Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just test the locale and use two different SimpleDateFormat patterns?

Comment: Trying to avoid it, i also have arabic (different number letters) so i'm just trying to find a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want specific patterns, you have to test the locale and apply the format you want.

For your english and chinese formats :

```
CharSequence englishDate = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy", date);
CharSequence chineseDate = DateFormat.format("yyyy年MM月dd日", date);
```

Results are :
`25/05/2016` and `2016年05月25日`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work good. I need a very specific format - dd/MM/yyyy